# Finding area boundes by polar curves

Tags: definite-integrals, polar-coordinates

Find the area bounded by $r \le 4sin(t), \frac{\pi}{3} \le t$

Well, when I graph it with Geogebra I get an entire circunference, but what values should I plot for the definite integral? Would it be from $\frac{\pi}{3}$ to $2 \pi$?

Comment: What is the interval for $t$ that makes one circle?

Comment: It's from 0 to $2 \pi$

Comment: Sorry, that's not right. If you have a TI 83 or 84, you can plot it from $0$ to $\pi$ and see that you get one full circle. From $\pi$ to $2\pi$ it traces the same circle again. With this info you should be able to set up the polar integral

Answer (score 1):

The range of $t$ for the definite integral should be $0<t<\pi/3$. So, the area integral is,

$$\int_0^{\pi/3}\int_0^{4\sin (t)}rdrdt=8\int_0^{\pi/3}\sin^2(t)dt=\frac{4}{3}\pi-\sqrt{3}$$

[image]

Comment: Why do you think that is the range for $t$?

Comment: $t$ is the angle variable in the polar coordinates and $t \le \pi/3$ is specified in the problem.

Comment: He wrote $\frac{\pi}{3} \le t$ and this was questioned in the comments.  Perhaps it should be $\frac{\pi}{3} \le t\le \frac{4\pi}{3}$?

Comment: Please see the diagram in the answer.

Comment: Okay, so he either asked for $0\le t \le \frac{\pi}{3} $ or $\frac{\pi}{3} \le t \le \pi$ (probably the latter).  I guess your interpretation is fine!  Thanks.